# addResourcePath not setting www

Tags: r, shiny

I have html file which calls some images like `<img src="1.png">` If I put it in `www` folder where app is stored. It works fine (both HTML and images loaded properly). But I need to wrap it in a package so I am using `shiny::addResourcePath("www", path)` and then calling html via `includeHTML( )` It does not work. `includeHTML( )` does not interact with the path set by `shiny::addResourcePath( )` If I use `system.file(package = "stats")` in **includeHTML( )** it loads html but not images in the html as path in the image refers to static path which is **www** Folder structure of html and images is as follows. Is there any way to set www path dynamically and ask shiny app to refer there?

```
assets
    └── 1.png
    └── 11.png
    └── 2.png
    └── 22.png
    └── sample.html
```